# How to split a MySQL field into two and compare string between both fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a field in my MySQL table financial_year that contains values like below

```
01-04-2010-31-03-2011
01-04-2011-31-03-2012
01-04-2013-31-03-2014
```

and I have a date suppose 03-05-2011

and want to get the financial year in which this date lies.

I tried it by using

```
SELECT financial_year 
FROM financial_years 
WHERE '03-05-2011' IS BETWEEN SPLIT("-", financial_year)
```

but it did not work.

Comment: why was your table designed this way? To make the developers work harder for their remuneration?

Comment: since it's fixed length, you may consider split by length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **LEFT()** and **RIGHT()** since the length on your values is fixed and use **STR_TO_DATE()** to convert your string to date. Here is the example:

```
SELECT financial_year
FROM financial_years
WHERE STR_TO_DATE('03-05-2011','%d-%m-%Y') >= DATE( LEFT(financial_year,10) )
AND STR_TO_DATE('03-05-2011','%d-%m-%Y') <= DATE( RIGHT(financial_year,10) );
```

If the data type of financial_year is **VARCHAR()** you should use **STR_TO_DATE()** too like on this one

```
STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(financial_year,10),'%d-%m-%Y')
```

and

```
STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT(financial_year,10),'%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: What is the data type of financial_year?

Answer (score 0):

The following code did work

```
SELECT financial_year
FROM financial_years
WHERE STR_TO_DATE('03-01-2012','%d-%m-%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE( LEFT(financial_year,10),'%d-%m-%Y' )
AND STR_TO_DATE('03-01-2012','%d-%m-%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE( RIGHT(financial_year,10),'%d-%m-%Y' );
```